# Cannot load DetailView template . URL is generated incorrectly

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am a beginner in Django and I am learning CBV's.

I used Django' built in User class to create several users on my website and then i created the following views below .

The url generated for my user_list view is http://127.0.0.1:8000/basicapp/user_list/ and works. It shows
the users

The url generated  my user_detail view is http://127.0.0.1:8000/basicapp/1/ (2,3...and so one) and works when manually entered. It shows the user detail

The problem is this:

In the user_list.html,   i add : `<a href="{{person.id}}"`and 
In the url.py I add: `url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$',views.UserDetailView.as_view(),name='detail')`

So, when the user list page loads with my users as links , when i hover over the links i get a path like:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/basicapp/user_list/1 - this link does not work. I click on it and does not do anything

I should be  geting :

http://127.0.0.1:8000/basicapp/1 . This link does work because i tested it manually.

I think I am doing womething wrong in the urls.py but i am not sure. The regex i took was from a training video and have only a general  idea about it does.

```
basicapp/views.py:

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import View,TemplateView,ListView,DetailView

class UserView(ListView):
        context_object_name='users'
        model=models.User
        template_name='basicapp/user_list.html'

class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name='user_detail'
    model=models.User
    template_name='basicapp/user_detail.html'

basicapp/urls.py:

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from basicapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^user_list/',views.UserView.as_view(),name='list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$',views.UserDetailView.as_view(),name='detail')

]
```

user_list.html

```
user_list.html:
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
<title>User page</title>
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <ol>
      {%for person in users %}
          <li><a href="{{person.id}}">{{person}} and {{person.id}}</a></li>
      {%endfor%}
    </ol>
{% endblock content %}
```

user_detail.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>user_detail</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron">

      <h1>User Profile Page</h1>
      <p>First name : {{user_detail.first_name}}</p>
      <p>Last Name: {{user_detail.last_name}}</p>
      <p>Email: {{user_detail.email}}</p>


    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template you need to use the [`url` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url), with a reference to the url name and any parameters:

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' person.id %}">{{person}} and {{person.id}}</a>
```

Comment: it finally worked . Thanks so much . I've been staring at the screen for 2 days. :)

Comment: No problem. If it worked, feel free to mark this as the answer to your question.